# How to import .sql file in selenium so that i can execute multiple scripts in selenium?

Tags: mysql, sql, selenium, selenium-webdriver

also how to execute multiple command in selenium like i want to insert update and then select * from employee how will i perform that?

Answer (score 0):

Read the `.sql` file using below code.

```
 File ff=new File("path to your sql file");
 FileReader fr=new FileReader(ff);

 String s;

 while(br.read()!=-1)
 {
     s = br.readLine();   // here is your all queries
 }
```

Now you can create a collection to iterate through all the queries or fire the execute query inside the file read loop. Remember to use execute() method.

This will return a boolean. TRUE indicates the result is a ResultSet and FALSE indicates it has the int value which denotes number of rows affected by the query.